# How to know more about creatures?

Tags: diablo-iii

How to know in the game information about creatures I'm fighting with (their strong and weak sides like: spell immunity, etc.)?

Thank you.

EDITED: I've tried to Google in order to find any information about creatures, but failed to find any good reference. Because of that I've changed the question to find any information about creatures, not in-game only.

Answer (score 4):

Like the other posters have said, the information has been simplified.

However, there are specific buffs a magic or elite monster may have. As you get to higher difficulties a monster could possibly have multiple of these leading to some extremely tough mobs (harder than the bosses!)

EDIT: Here is another good guide in pdf form on various monster difficulties and statuses: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71014109/Darkie%27s%20tiny%20guide.pdf

**Arcane Enchanted** - Monsters enchanted with Arcane Enchanted trait deal additional arcane damage and have the ability to summon orbs which fire rotating arcane beams

**Avenger** - When a Champion group imbued with Avenger arrives, the death of each group member imbues the remaining Champions with added power/size as they wreak their frenzied vengeance on the Hero

**Desecrator** - A monster with Desecrator trait creates a glowing void zone beneath the targeted hero that damages the hero. Desecration will activate a few seconds after it appears on the floor, giving you time to get out of the void zone.

**Electrified** - A monster with the Electrified trait has higher lightning resistance, deals additional lightning damage and discharges sparks across the floor in random directions when struck.

**Extra Health** - Bestows the imbued monster with extra HP

**Fast** - This makes monsters run, attack and cast magic faster

**Fire Chains** - Champion backs are attached by a fire chain. The Hero suffers damage if he touches or even gets near one of the fire links.

**Frozen** - Monsters with the Frozen affix can summon frost orbs that grow and eventually explode causing cold damage and applying a Chill and a Freeze debuff

**Health Link** - Health Link reduces the amount of damage taken by the champion with that trait by linking his HP to that of all other Health Link champions in the area

**Horde** - Horde increases the squad of minions that spawn with a rare monster, crowding the battlefield

**Illusionist** - The Illusionist trait imbues a creature with the ability to create clones of itself at much lower health levels

**Invulnerable Minions** - Monsters imbued with this trait arrive with a squad of indestructible puppet minions and an expanded heath pool

**Jailer** - This trait gives monsters the ability to immobilize the Hero in a conjured prison

**Knockback** - Knockback allows monsters to push back the player a short/long distance with each connecting blow, whether it be ranged or melee. Also, slows player.

**Missile Dampening** - Creatures imbued with the trait generate a reddish sphere around themselves. Any projectile entering this sphere moves 90% slower than normal

**Molten** - Monsters that spawn with this trait deal extra fire damage. In addition, they leave trailing pools of lava that deal fire damage over time. Any non-minion monster killed with this trait leaves a time bomb that will explode after 3 seconds, dealing large amounts of fire damage

**Mortar** - Monsters with mortar can lob several fireballs that deal splash damage on impact. Mortar lobs a burst of 3 fireballs towards the player, even over obstacles, but will always lob over a character in melee distance.

**Nightmarish** - Nightmarish monsters have a chance to fear the player on hit and can be triggered from both melee and ranged attacks

**Plagued** - Monsters enchanted with Plagued leave pools of poisonous green goo around them

**Shielding** - This trait gives the monster a brief period of invulnerability to all forms of damage. Shielding mobs have green glow around them before they activate the shield.

**Teleporter** - Gives the monster the ability to teleport to a nearby location

**Reflect Damage** - When you strike a Reflect Damage imbued foe with any attack, you suffer automatic damage in return

**Waller** - Monsters with Waller can summon earthen walls between the player and the monster, or sometimes behind the player to prevent escape. Waller mobs are different between elites and champions. Elite (boss with minions) create a box around the players to keep them in a general area, while champion packs create single walls in front or behind the player.

**Vampiric**- This trait allows monster to (figuratively) feast on the damage they inflict to you by turning it into health for themselves

**Vortex** - Grants the ability to forcibly pull the player right next to the monster but does not pull player through objects.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/ua7i7/monster_affixes/

Comment: Thank you Casty, the best answer so far. Though it still is not clear what is the best counter vs these monsters. Let's assume, I've identified the monster type is "Nightmarish": Nightmarish monsters have a chance to fear the player on hit and can be triggered from both melee and ranged attacks. What is the best treat for them? Any guides? Thanks.

Comment: In general, popping cooldowns that make you invunerable against certain effects such as "Nightmarish" would be best. There are likely passives or runes from skills that you could use against various types too. Unfortunately, sometimes a monster has the WORST combinations possible. In that case, many people just reload the game or avoid those monsters entirely, especially in hardcore.

In case you didn't see the edit, here is a more detailed guide than the above on specific strategies against certain types: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71014109/Darkie%27s%20tiny%20guide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The game has been simplified a bit from previous incarnations of the franchise, so information like weaknesses, strengths, etc. has been left out.

Edit: Correction, you can see monster HP from the options. Enable health bars and numerical health.

Comment: You can actually display floating monster health bars including numbers in the options.

Comment: Numbers in the options? Could you please be more clear where to see those numbers? Thank you

Comment: @Budda this is under your gameplay settings in the global Diablo III options. (You can tell it to both show all damage/life gain numbers and show monster HP bars.)

Comment: The game may have been somewhat simplified by the removal of immunities, but monsters do have differing degrees of resistance or weakness to different damage sources, and that information would be useful. I haven't been able to find any post-release information on what monsters have which resistances/weaknesses, but there's plenty of pre-release info that they wanted resistances to be a factor, if not one that would completely force co-op play, e.g. [this interview](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/16947-diablofans-exclusive-jay-wilson/).

Answer (score 1):

Floating monster health bars can be turned on **using the "V" key** (provided you don't change that hotkey).  I hit it all the time by accident, but I like it on.

For out of game info on monsters you can check out http://d3db.com/npc , and also http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/ .  Both are database style sites that give info on the monsters based on game data.  Particularly important, you can find out the levels of monsters from these sites, which can be used to calculate [the experience you'll get for killing them](http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/diablo-3-experience-points-explained.html).

If you are specifically interested in uniques (monsters with Purple names and "flavor text") you can find a list [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?824714-Complete-List-of-unique-Elite-monsters-in-Diablo-3).  These monsters, in addition to more general elites/champions, tend to have [special traits](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41071-spoiler-diablo-iii-monster-traits/#entry864263) which give them unique powers.

Comment: I don't really need to have information about experience.

Comment: The databases content information such as hitpoints, movement speed, and level.  If you don't care about experience I think others reading this question would, but you may care about monster level for other reasons such as [calculating damage reduction](http://mmo-mechanics.com/swtor/forums/Thread-Diablo-3-formula-list).

Answer (score 1):

Enemies are not "strong" or "weak" against any magic, melee, or range class.  Their abilities are just annoying and increase the difficulty of the game.

I assume this is the simple answer you were looking for.  I tried looking into the sites that EBongo linked but one wouldn't work properly and the other one was only complete for normal difficulty, so I'm not sure where you can go to find any information on the mobs off server.

But no, there are no skills that do any more or less damage to any of the enchanted monsters.

Comment: Brady guide tells that if monster is "Arcane Enchanted" he will have additional resistance to Arcane damage. I guess it's applicable for all other treats

Answer (score 0):

AN IMPRESSIVE "Diablo 3 Brady Guide" contains a lot of information about game and as part of that pretty solid description of game creatures. It contains also tips whom to kill first in battle.

It looks that can be bought in form of printed colored book (and can be an awesome gift for your friend) or downloaded from torrent in form of high quality colored pdf.

https://www.google.ca/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=double+locked+singletone#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=double%20locked%20singletone&cp=20&gs_id=3&xhr=t&q=Diablo%203%20Brady%20Guide&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Diablo+3+Brady+Guide&aq=0&aqi=g2g-b2&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=79e49ec59cb9bd64&biw=1820&bih=995

looks like it has an official web site as well: http://www.bradygames.com/index.aspx